# iPhone: Fade transition between two RootViewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, transition

`Obj-C` or `MonoTouch C#` answers are fine.

The initial UIWindow's RootViewController is a simple login screen.

```
window.RootViewController = loginScreen;
```

After login, I set the Root to the main app

```
window.RootViewController = theAppScreen;
```

How do I Fade-transition between the two RootViewControllers in this instance?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I might suggest a different approach that will get you your animation. Just go to the `theAppScreen` controller *first*, and if you need the user to log in, have it do the `presentViewController` to get to the `loginScreen` (you don't have to animate this step if you want it look like it went directly to the login screen). That way, when you've successfully logged in, the loginScreen can just `dismissViewControllerAnimated` and you've got your animation back to the main `theAppScreen`. (Obviously, if you want the fade effect, don't forget to set the controller's `modalTransitionStyle` to `UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve`.)

If you're dead set on changing your `rootViewController`, the only way I can think of doing it (and I don't like it) would be to do something like:

```
MainAppViewController *controller = [[MainAppViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainAppViewController" bundle:nil];

// animate the modal presentation

controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:controller 
                                             animated:YES
                                           completion:^{

    // and then get rid of it as a modal

    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    // and set it as your rootview controller

    self.window.rootViewController = controller;
}];
```

The first technique seems much cleaner to me.

Comment: As danh suggested, if you're supporting iOS 4 or earlier, use the deprecated `presentModalViewController` and `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`. Otherwise, stick with `presentViewController` and `dismissViewControllerAnimated`.

Comment: The first approach seems not working well when the `theAppScreen ` is a `UITabBarController`

Comment: @Malloc Works fine for me. Are you putting this in your `UITabBarController` subclass? When you say "seems not working well", how so?

Comment: FWIW, the second, disliked, approach certainly doesn't work on iOS 8. "Trying to dismiss the presentation controller while transitioning already.". You can finagle things by removing the dismissViewControllerAnimated call.

Answer (score 3):

This is MT code of @Robert Ryan's technique (although I agree with his suggestion that `theAppScreen` is probably the "correct" `RootViewController`):

```
void DissolveIn (UIWindow window, UIViewController newController)
{
  newController.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve;
  window.RootViewController.PresentViewController (newController, true, () => 
  {
    window.RootViewController.DismissViewController (false, null);
    window.RootViewController = newController;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
window.RootViewController = theAppScreen;

loginScreen.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[theAppScreen presentModalViewController:loginScreen animated:NO];
```

loginScreen can dismiss itself when done: `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

The NO on the first animation will make the loginScreen appear without any visibility of the theAppScreen beneath it.  The animated = YES on completion will provide the cross-dissolve.